# Initialize ViewModel with defaults values

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, viewmodel

I have the following code for a simple ViewModel with which I want to update 3 labels:

```
struct State {
    var timeLabelText: String?
    var timeLabelHidden: Bool
    var dayLabelText: String
    var dateLabelText: String
}

class ViewModel {
    var state: State = State(timeLabelText: nil, timeLabelHidden: true, dayLabelText: "Day 0", dateLabelText: "June 19, 2017") {
        didSet {
            callback(state)
        }
    }

    var callback: ((State) -> Void)

    init(callback: @escaping (State) -> Void) {
        self.callback = callback
        callback(state)
    }

    var date: String {
        get {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long

            return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        }
    }
}
```

This will initialize my UI with the default values from the `State`. But for the `dateLabelText` I want to initialize it with the actual date, before the UI is displayed.

Where is the right place to do this ? Should I just go and do it inside the ViewModel initializer ?

```
init(callback: @escaping (State) -> Void) {
    self.callback = callback
    state.dateLabelText = date  // add this here 
    callback(state)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making it a static property:

```
class ViewModel {
    var state: State = State(timeLabelText: nil, timeLabelHidden: true, dayLabelText: "Day 0", dateLabelText: ViewModel.date) {
        didSet {
            callback(state)
        }
    }

    var callback: ((State) -> Void)

    init(callback: @escaping (State) -> Void) {
        self.callback = callback
        callback(state)
    }

    static private var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
        return dateFormatter
    }()

    static var date: String {
        get {
            return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I also separated out the `dateFormatter` so it's only initialized once. Creation of `DateFormatter`s is a relatively expensive operation that shouldn't be repeated unless necessary.

Also be aware that with your approach the date will be different every time it's accessed. This type of functionality may be better described as a function rather than a property.

Comment: Great idea. Thank you. But I don't understand, why do you say that the date  should be a method rather than property ?

Comment: Every time you call `thing.date` you're formatting the current date, so every time it's accessed it will be using a different DateTime. Generally that type of behavior is better expressed as a method. Properties generally are meant to store and relay defined information, not information that changes every time it's accessed. Not a big deal, just my preference :)

Comment: Ohh, ok, I think you got a point. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!